# solving a congruence modulo $1002$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

My question is about number theory, about congruences.

I need to solve the congruence $2^{1002}$ modulo $1002$.

I try to apply Chinese remainder,

Fermat's little theorem

and a few theorems more but i think i am on the wrong way:(

I need a hint to start the solution i think...

$2^{1002}$ is congruent to which number modulo $1002$?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Type in $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $a^n \bmod m = a^{(n \;\bmod \; \varphi(m))} \bmod m$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function. Since $1002  = 2 \times 3 \times 167$ we have $\varphi(1002)=1\times 2 \times 166= 332$. Therefore 
$$2^{1002} \equiv 2^{(1002 \;\bmod \; 332)} \equiv 2^6 \equiv 64 \pmod{1002}
$$

Comment: I don't think you can use Euler's theorem here, since $2$ and $1002$ are not relatively prime. Am I missing something?

Comment: No you are right. The answer is correct by accident. I just asked a question about the conditions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565449/when-is-an-equiv-an-bmod-varphim-pmod-m-valid

Comment: Great, thanks! I was going to ask the exact same question! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take:
1002 = 3 *2 * 167

Reminder by 6 (apply Chinese) = 4
Reminder by 167 (apply fermat's ) = 64

So reminder by 1002 (apply Chinese again) = 64.