# Solving a congruence $x^{17} \equiv 243 \pmod{257}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to solve the following congruence:

$x^{17} \equiv 243 \pmod{257}$

I have worked out that the $\gcd(243,257)=1$ and that $243=3^5$

So $x^{17} \equiv 3^5 \pmod{257}$

and I don't really understand what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $257$ is a prime number by Fermat's little theorem $a^{256}\equiv 1\mod 257\ \forall a, 257\not|a$ Now, let us find if there is a solution of the form $3^y$. If there is then the equation will become $$3^{17y-5}\equiv 1\mod 257\Rightarrow 256|17y-5$$ $y=181$ is a solution to this. So $x=3^{181}$ is one solution and all the solutions of the form $3^y$ can be obtained by solving the linear Diphontaine equation $$17y-256z=5$$. 
Now, if there are solutions of the form $3^ya$ where $a$ does not contain $3$ as a prime factor then the equation will read as $$a^{17}3^{17y-5}\equiv 1\mod 257$$
But I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 5):

We want to solve $x^{17} \equiv 3^5 \pmod{257}$. Raise both sides to the power $15$ to get
$$x^{255} \equiv 3^{75} \pmod{257},$$
or equivalently $x^{-1} \equiv 3^{75} \pmod {257}$. Thus $x \equiv 3^{-75} \equiv 28 \pmod{257}$.

Comment: Can you explain me $3^{-75}\equiv28 \mod(257)$  please.....

Comment: @Satvik Mashkaria: It is just the multiplicative inverse of $3^{75}$ modulo $257$. Equivalently, I claim that $28 \cdot 3^{75} \equiv 1 \pmod{257}$.

Comment: That is what I am asking. Did you multiply $28$ with $3^{75}$ ??

Comment: @Satvik Mashkaria: You mean how to calculate $3^{-75} \pmod{257}$? Well, we already know that $3^{5} \equiv 243 \pmod{257}$, so we just have to calculate $243^{15} \pmod {257}$ and take the modular inverse. To do this, we can use exponentiation by squaring: $243^{2} \equiv 196 \pmod{257}$, $243^4 \equiv 192^2 \equiv 123 \pmod{257}$, $243^{8} \equiv 123^2 \equiv 223 \pmod{257}$, $243^{16} \equiv 223^2 \equiv 128 \pmod{256}$. Now $243^{-1} \equiv 55 \pmod{257}$, so $243^{15} \equiv 128 \cdot 55 \equiv 101 \pmod{257}$. Thus $3^{-75} \equiv 243^{-15} \equiv 28 \pmod{256}$.

Comment: @Satvik Mashkaria: Sorry for the couple of typos, all (mod $256$)s should of course be (mod $257$). It's too late to edit the comment. To find the inverses of $243$ and $101$ you can use the Euclidean algorithm. (Or raise them to the power $255$ by exponentiation by squaring.)

Comment: I think this is the best answer as it guarantees the uniqueness of the solution .

Answer (score 2):

We have the following facts: $\gcd(3,257)=1,\,$ $\varphi(257)=256,\,$ and 3 is a primitive root mod 257. From the first two we know, see e.g. [When is $a^n \equiv a^{(n \;\bmod \; \varphi(m))} \pmod m$ valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565449/when-is-an-equiv-an-bmod-varphim-pmod-m-valid),
$$3^n \equiv 3^{(n \;\bmod \; \varphi(257))} \equiv 3^{(n \;\bmod \; 256)}  \pmod {257}$$
Make the Ansatz $x=3^y$, then
$$x^{17}\equiv 3^5 \pmod {257} \iff 3^{17y-5}\equiv 1 \equiv 3^0 \pmod {257}$$
Now solve $17y-5\equiv 0 \pmod {256}\,$. The multiplicative inverse is $17^{-1} \equiv 241 \pmod {256}\,$ and $y=5\times 241 \equiv 181 \pmod {256}.\,$ Therefore  a solution is$$x=3^y=3^{181} \equiv 28 \pmod {257}.$$
Now you can check that $28^{17} \equiv 243 \pmod {257}.$